# AutoKey Error on Ubuntu Gnome 15.04

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome, autokey

AutoKey works fine on Ubuntu 15.04.  However on Ubuntu Gnome 15.04 I get the following errors:

```
Error starting interface. Keyboard monitoring will be disabled.
Check your system/configuration.
Can't connect to display ":1": No protocol specified

Fatal error starting AutoKey.
Service instance has no attribute 'phraseRunner'
```

Is there something missing that I should install?

Comment: same problem and no idea :\

Comment: It works fine on Ubuntu Mate 15.04 too. Very strange.

Comment: if you don't mind me asking how did you install this it isn't in the ubuntu software center

Comment: I installed it by having ran `sudo apt install autokey-gtk`

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a strange issue between changes in `python-xlib` and DBus, but I am unable to find the exact issue. As a temporary workaround, you can disable X server access control with a simple

```
xhost +
```

before running AutoKey. Not a secure or ideal solution, but it works. You can add this to your `./profile` to make sure it runs before AutoKey starts.

Here are some related bugs that cause the same error, though it *seems* that they were already fixed a couple years ago:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-xlib/+bug/1432889
- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=666721
- https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=623507